# Give Different Error pages for Variations site in Sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-masterpage, variations

I have a Web Applcation which contains a Publishing Site with Variations feature enabled. The following is an example URL for the site http://test-server.com/en

I have enabled a custom error page for English Site. But I want to enable a new Custom Error page for Arabic site with the following URL http://test-server.com/ar.

So overall there should be two Error pages one for Arabic and one for English. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is PowerShell to set your page not found URL:

```
$spsite = Get-SPSite "Web site URL"
$spsite.filenotfoundurl
$spsite.filenotfoundurl = "/sites/yoursite/Pages/PageNotFoundError.aspx"
```

Besides, customizing the 404 Redirection in SharePoint for your reference:

https://www.chakkaradeep.com/2009/06/23/customizing-the-404-redirection-in-sharepoint/